# Use both fixed and flexible elements in GridBaglayout row (or column)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to display two buttons next to a text field:

[image: image description]

I gave up on the text already, but I really need the two buttons to remain small while the text field should expand with the window:

[image: image description]

Currently, I use this layouts:

[image: image description]

The text field and the two buttons are both in JPanel.

```
//JPanel group  - the container
//List<JComponent> - the conponents added to JPanel
//int[] weights - weights of components
GridBagLayout lay = new GridBagLayout();

for(int i=0,l=fields.size(); i<l; i++) {
  InputDef field = fields.get(i);

  GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
  if(weights.length<i) {
    c.weightx = weights[i]; 
  }
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  lay.setConstraints(field.getField(), c);
}
group.setLayout(lay);
```

In the documentation I see that for the components to fill their area horizontally, you should set the `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL` to the constraints of the components.

Further, I read that you should set different `GridBagConstraints#weightx` to make the elements take different amount of space.

However running the code above doesn't do anything - the JPanel looks exactly the same with no layout manager whatsoever.

Comment: You need to use `fill`/`weightx` or `fill`/`weighty` in combination. For example `fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; weightx = 1.0;` component will grab horizontal space , other components in that row with `fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE; weightx = 0;` will have fixed size. Read more in [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).